# How to create an object instance of a typescript class from within plain js using AMD modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, amd

Lets say I have the following file `tests.ts`:

```
module tests {

    export class Greeter
    {
        sayHello() {
            console.log("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

And compiling it as and AMD module. How exactly do I create an object instance of Greeter in a regular JavaScript (not typescript!) file?

I was thinking of something like:

```
require(['tests', function(tests) {
    var greeter = new tests.Greeter();
    greeter.sayHello();
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work - the debugger shows me tests is of `__proto__` but I can't find a member 'Greeter' in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgotten the `export` keyword on the top-level `module`, so that top code block doesn't actually export anything visible as an external module.

Also, refer to the [Modules in TypeScript](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript) "Needless Namespacing" pitfall:

> If you're converting a program from internal modules to external
>   modules, it can be easy to end up with a file that looks like this:

*shapes.ts*

```
 export module Shapes {
     export class Triangle { /* ... */ }
     export class Square { /* ... */ } }
 }
```

> The top-level module here Shapes wraps up Triangle and Square for no
>   reason. This is confusing and annoying for consumers of your module:

*shapeConsumer.ts*

```
 import shapes = require('./shapes'); var t = new
 shapes.Shapes.Triangle(); // shapes.Shapes?
```

> A key feature of external modules in TypeScript is that two different
>   external modules will never contribute names to the same scope.
>   Because the consumer of an external module decides what name to assign
>   it, there's no need to proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a
>   namespace.
>
> To reiterate why you shouldn't try to namespace your external module
>   contents, the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical
>   grouping of constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the
>   external module file itself is already a logical grouping, and its
>   top-level name is defined by the code that imports it, it's
>   unnecessary to use an additional module layer for exported objects.